# What does "long" refer to?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

In *Eternals* (2021), Ikarus meet Ajak in South Dakota:

> Ikarus: How **long** do we have?
>
> Ajak: Seven days.
>
> Ikarus: Good. We completed our mission.

What does "long" refer to?

Comment: _"How much time do we have?"_ (I know this should be an answer, but I don't know the _why_ of the English language)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/how_long);

> **Adverb**
>
> Used literally: **for what duration.**
>
> [e.g.] How long have you lived in Chicago?
> He won't tell me how long he is going to stay.